# How to get the number of times a string is repeated in PHP

Tags: php, string

In a string like `"abc fox fox fox ghi xyz"` how can i get the number of times 'fox' is repeated in the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string = 'abc fox fox fox ghi xyz';

$substring = 'fox';

$substringCount = substr_count($string, $substring);

echo '"' . $substring . '" appears in "' . $string . '" ' . $substringCount . ' times';
```

Comment: There's a builtin for that? Wow! 
Named differently from every other string function, I presume! ;)

Comment: PHP consistency can be a bit tricky sometimes... but php.net is only a few clicks away 99% of the time :)

Comment: found this function today, was hard to find, not being next to the str* or str_* functions

Comment: Ha! substringCount! That's awesome, a very elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`substr_count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) method is indeed very nice, but if you have more needs (for example to match only whole words) here is a regex version using [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and word boundaries:

```
$nb_of_matches = preg_match_all('/\bfox\b/', $subject);
```

Quite simple too :-)